# How to make a slider iterate in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, addlayer

I have a bunch of layers displayed, and I can make a slider so I can click through the layers (see code). So how do I make the slider bar display from 0 to NumLayers and iterate by 1 layer? (Right now I see a slider from 0 to 1 and I have to slide the bar very carefully to end up on a layer of interest).

```
var slider = ui.Slider(); 

slider.onSlide(function(value) {

  var int_value = value * (Map.layers().length() - 1) >> 0;

  Map.layers().get(int_value).setOpacity(1);

  for (var i = int_value + 1; i < Map.layers().length(); i++) {

    Map.layers().get(i).setOpacity(0);

}

});

print(slider);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works well. Now If I can just get the system to show the label name as I slide between layers....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a slider with the min, max and step argument. Then make a onchange function where all maps are set to opacity 0, except for the selected map.

```
// make a slider
var slider = ui.Slider({min: 0, 
                        max: Map.layers().length() - 1, 
                        value: 0, 
                        step: 1});
print(slider);

slider.onSlide(function(value) {
  
  // set opacity all layers 0
  for (var i = 0; i < Map.layers().length(); i++) {
    Map.layers().get(i).setOpacity(0);
  }
  
  // set opacity slided layer to 1
  Map.layers().get(value).setOpacity(1);
});
```

Note that with a large number of layers a client-side for loop may not be preferable. [Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7685c42db6259f0069676f041def339d)

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I've noted that the last layer displayed is visible but the slider bar doesn't indicate number of layers total. I have to click to advance to layer 2 and then back to layer 1 to view layer 1. The full number of layers available in the slider doesn't show until I view the last layer. 
This isn't really a problem, but it would be nice to tidy up the display. 
It would also be nice to display the layer name of the active layer only. I'm assuming this would have to be done in the slider.onSlide{} part, but I can't seem to remove the name of the previous layers viewed.